# Print To Zebra Printer TLP 3842

Tags: c#, .net, text-files, zebra-printers, printdocument

How can I print to Zebra Printer TLP 3842 using EPL Programming? The printer doesn't support Zebra Printer Language (ZPL) and I am using PrintDocument(). I been on this problem for two weeks and can't figure it out. This what I have so far in my code, that actually runs the printer:

```
private System.ComponentModel.Container Components;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button PrintButton;
    private Font PrintFont;
    private StreamReader StreamToPrint;

    private void PrintButton_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamToPrint = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\jcabrera\\Desktop\\MyFile.txt");
            //string ZPL_STRING = "^XA^LL440,^FO50,50^A0N,50,50^FDTesting Zebra Printer^FS^XZ";

            // ZPL Command(s)


            try
            {
                PrintFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
                PrintDocument PD = new PrintDocument();
                PD.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PD_PrintPage);
                PD.Print();

            }
            finally
            {
                StreamToPrint.Close();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void PD_PrintPage(object Sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
           PrintFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

        // Print each line of the file.
        while (count < linesPerPage &&
           ((line = StreamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count *
               PrintFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, PrintFont, Brushes.Black,
               leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }

        // If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (line != null)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.PrintButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 381);
        this.Text = "Print Example";

        PrintButton.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        PrintButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 110);
        PrintButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        PrintButton.TabIndex = 0;
        PrintButton.Text = "Print the file.";
        PrintButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 40);
        PrintButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(PrintButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(PrintButton);
    }
```

Using Windows Application project.

Comment: Why must you use EPL? The Zebra printer driver supports printing text and graphics through the PrintDocument API just fine.

Comment: I will try that out

Comment: @DourHighArch I got it working with graphics, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add RawPrinterHelperClass to your project, and then print like this

```
string ZPL_STRING = "^XA^LL440,^FO50,50^A0N,50,50^FDTesting Zebra Printer^FS^XZ";
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("PrinterName", ZPL_STRING)
```

C# Class
https://github.com/andyyou/SendToPrinter/blob/master/Printer/RawPrinterHelper.cs