# WPF Write Text to Image and send to Printer

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawstring, text-rendering

i want to create a little image containing a logo and multiple lines of text and send it directly to a printer. However im having trouble with textquality.

Currently im creating a Bitmap and render text to it via g.DrawString:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(240, 240);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;  // or AntiAlias
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.DrawString("Charge: 1911", new Font("Arial Narrow", 8.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(6,119));

PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
[...]
pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
    pd.Print();
g.Dispose();
```

This Code works so far as expected, except the textquality is too bad to actually print.
This is the current result:

with AntiAliasGridFit:

[image]

With AntiAlias:

[image]

This (or better) is the result that i want to achieve:

[image]

Now my question is, is there any way to get better textquality, maybe somehow using TextRenderer instead of Graphics?
It doesnt have to be a bitmap that I print. I just need to be able to also write a pre-existing image to it and send the whole document to a Printer afterwards.

Comment: Whats Your DPI on that printer ?

Comment: I can only check it in a few days, but its a labelprinter which is already printing very small text.

Comment: Do You know model of this printer ?

Comment: Hey, i was able to check just now. 
i will need to be able to print to a Zebra TLP3842 and a Brother QL-560.

Comment: You can try different approach from [that post check how to send ZPL to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754966/print-to-zebra-printer-tlp-3842) and from [this site](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/img-to-zpl-online) You can convert image to ZPL, [at this site You can check how label will look like](http://labelary.com/viewer.html). This will take You a while, but sending raw ZPL to printer will lead You to better quality

Comment: Oh alright i haven't tought about this way yet, first time trying to send stuff to a printer. I will have to look into it. Thanks so far for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging i found a solution to my problem.
Instead of creating a Bitmap and drawing text to it i directly draw text to the PrintPageEventArgs object of the PrintPage Method:

```
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(logoImg, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, xSize, ySize);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Charge: 19011", textFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0, new StringFormat());
}
```

Im not 100% sure why this works but i now have perfectly clear text like with vector graphics.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dliJv.jpg)